# limit google map area that can be selected by population density

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to work out if I can limit the area a user can select on a google map depending on population density in the area.

So for example, a user would be able to select a small area of a map in a high population area, and a large area of the map in a low population area.

The maximum area a person could select (regardless of population density) would be small (~50km to a side) and so I'd work with the average population density for an area.

Does anyone know if such a thing is possible using Googles Map API or would I have to import and query another data set or service?

Comment: Do you already have the population density data? Is your question more about the data, or about the UI aspect of limiting the selection range?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes.  You'd need to find the data, add it to a database that supports spatial queries, and then use event listeners to send the current viewport (bounding rectangle) of the map to the database to query for population within the given area.

Comment: Pekka; I do not have data sources yet, I wondered if google had population density information that I could query directly to achieve my goal.  I found reference to  google providing population density overlay information for business users - however I couldn't find anything in the API that looked useful.  The ref is here if you're interested; https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/demographics#query